# docker -ps --format output with substr

Tags: linux, bash, docker, sh, go-templates

There is a command: `docker ps --format "{{.ID}}\t{{.Command}}" --no-trunc` (used https://pkg.go.dev/text/template)

which outputs the full text of the `'{{.Command}}'` (which I need), but outputs too long `'{{.ID}}'`

I need to take the first 12 characters from `'{{.ID}}'` and all characters (`--no-trunc`) from `'{{.Command}}'`. How to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the ´printf` function in the Go template like this

```
docker ps --format "{{printf \"%.12s\" .ID}}\t{{.Command}}" --no-trunc
```